# How can I calculate scikit-learn rbf_kernel() with very large array?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, metrics

While using the `rbf_kernel()` function the array is too large and there is a memory issue, so I have to separate the data and calculate it.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
result = rbf_kernel([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], gamma=60) # A data:[1,1] , B data:[2,2], C data:[3,3]
```

And  `result`  looks like

```
  A B C
A 1 2 1
B 1 1 1
C 1 1 2
```

However, if I insert larger data, there is a memory issue.

```
result = rbf_kernel([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],.... ], gamma=60)
```

How can I extract the result without putting data all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
l = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5], ...]
newl = []
for i in range(0, len(l), 10):
    newl.append(rbf_kernel(l[i:i + 10]))
```